# I am trying to convert this crypto encrypt and decrypt js code into typescript for an Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, encryption

I am using crypto in node.js for encryption and decryption of user credentials, which works fine. On the other hand, I have to use the same approach to getting the exact result of encryption and decryption in Angular. As it's confirmed that crypto is not working in Angular. I would like to know any way to achieve the required result.

I added `npm i --save-dev @types/node` but this is not working for me. Also added crypto but the module was not found. I also use npm crypto-js encryption is done but not the same as my js method.

This is my js file code, I need to implement the same method in my Angular project:

```
'use strict';
const crypto = require('crypto');
const IV_LENGTH = 16;
encrypt(text: any, key: any) {
   console.log('Before Encrption Data is-->', text, key)
   let iv = crypto.randomBytes(this.IV_LENGTH);
   let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
   let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
   encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
   let returnable = iv.toString('hex') + ':' + encrypted.toString('hex');
   return returnable;

 }

 decrypt(text: any, key: any) {
   let textParts = text.split(':');
   let iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift(), 'hex');
   let encryptedText = Buffer.from(textParts.join(':'), 'hex');
   let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv);
   let decrypted = decipher.update(encryptedText);

   decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);

   return decrypted.toString();
 }
```

When I added crypto this type of error occurred:
[image]

Comment: [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) is part of Node.js, not JavaScript generally. Your Angular code runs in your users' browsers, where it won't be available (in the same way that your backend code doesn't have the Web APIs).

Comment: So, the question is how can I achieve this?